# CGPDF how to get hyperlink text

Tags: ios, pdf, cgpdf

I need to get table of context from my PDF and put it in UITableView. To do this  I need to retrieve text (Paragraph name) and page number. 
as PDF example I use apple documentation PDF

**PDF Contents Example**
UI Design Basics  - 8
Designing for iOS 7  - 9
Defer to Content  - 10
Provide Clarity  - 12
Use Depth to Communicate  - 16
iOS App Anatomy  - 22
**PDF END**

I have looked in [PDFReader](https://github.com/vfr/Reader) library and also in [this link](http://ipdfdev.com/2011/06/21/links-navigation-in-a-pdf-document-on-iphone-and-ipad/) and find solution how to get page number only (8, 9, 10, 12, 16, 22). But can not find how to get Paragraph names (UI Design Basics, Designing for iOS 7, etc).
Also tried to use ReaderDocumentOutline.h/m from PDFReader lib to get Paragraph names - but it is return only Name from first page.

May be some one have idea how to handle this? Thx for Help

Answer (score 0):

I have find solution [here](https://github.com/RobinQu/RMag/blob/master/Classes/RPDFDocumentOutline.m)

it return page num + outline text.